# Como passar uma URL no Parâmetro de uma API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Como passar uma URL para um API

```
public class HTTPController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("URL={URL}")]
    public JsonResult GETURL(string URL)
    {
    }
}
```

No entanto ao passar por exemplo `https://google.pt` isto não interpreta como parâmetro

Eu tentei passar assim "http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.pt" mas nao funciona na mesma

Comment: Como está passando?

Comment: http://localhost/HTTP/GETURL/URL=http://google.pt

Comment: Esqueci de perguntar controller? Cara coloque mais informações ...

Comment: chama-se http eu actualizei o codigo

Comment: tentei assim mas nao funciona localhost/HTTP/GETURL/URL=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.pt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rota gerada pelo seu código será:

```
/http/URL={paramêtro}
```

Passar o parâmetro `https://google.pt` não funciona porque não é possível passar parâmetros com `/` via rota, caso queira fazer isso, terá que encodar o parâmetro de alguma forma.

De qualquer forma recomendo passa-lo via query string. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public JsonResult GETURL([FromQuery] string URL)
```

Rota gerada:

```
/http/geturl?URL={paramêtro}
```

Comment: Encodei assim http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.pt mas nao funcionou

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou normal encodando. Fique atento a rota da sua action pra ver se ta batendo certinho. Na minha resposta eu coloquei a rota que seu código gera.

Comment: usei Base64 Encode e funciounou cetinho